# slideToggle(), toggle div up and push the above div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[Here's JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JftGd/)

Everything's explained there in the fiddle.

Here, div is toggling below, but what i want is div should toggle upwards and push the above div up.
i.e. the div which is there with text will go up as heading.

*Thanks*

Comment: We shouldn't have to click out just to get a feel for your question and see your code. Fiddles are helpful as supplementary, demonstrative material, but please try to contain as much (pertinent) info in the question itself.

Comment: [Check this] http://jsfiddle.net/JftGd/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it for ya: http://jsfiddle.net/JftGd/2/

What I did was wrapped the paragraphs in a div, and added a `.slideToggle()` to that div in the `click` event function.

Hope this is what you were looking for :)

Comment: @ Chrish, some more help :) ... i want, let's say, some percent of text to be shown, i.e. when it toggle's, the text should be visible. toggle div should overlay the text.

Comment: @harnish You can't (at least, not using `slideToggle()`), because when an element slides closed, it is set to `display: none;` by jQuery, so even if you leave a space where there should be text showing, it disappears: http://jsfiddle.net/JftGd/14/

Comment: Can we play with z-index property of css

Comment: @harnish `z-index` won't work because when the div with the paragraphs slides up, jQuery adds `display: none;` to the element automatically, therefore it's hidden from the DOM.

Comment: @harnish nice, here it is again without the padding and negative margins: http://jsfiddle.net/JftGd/16/

Comment: it looks better now. **Cheers**

Answer (score 0):

Put the the text in another div and also slide toggle it.